# On-disk Data Structure/Library for Logging

Tags: logging, data-structures, datastore, data-storage

Is there a library or engine that I can embed in my system for writing out append-only data? In particular, I need something that can handle binary data, and which handle entry lookups (preferably O(log n) or better) as well as can be read forwards or backwards. I've already built out a custom file format, but I don't think that's scalable, and I'd prefer to use already-built and tested code. I'm looking for something that can be used to store log data, in particular.

Alternatively, what's the best way to represent such data on-disk? My current format looks like:

```
| size | protobuf-record | size |
```

where protobuf-record is a protobuf-formatted entry, flanked with its size (as a 32-bit unsigned integer). This allows me to scan forward and backward. I'm using a separate K-V store (in this case, Tokyo Cabinet) as an index into the data for lookup.

One property I'm looking for, in fact, is entries should not be insertable without detection in the file format.

Is what I'm looking for something that's been done before, or should I just continue by improving my custom file format?

Comment: Can you use extra file to store links to records?

Comment: Yes; external (i.e. separate file) indexes are possible. The primary file can contain just the records and be append only.